# NodeMCU (Arduino IDE) - after power off, sketch doesn't start

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I made a project that will send GPS coordinates to a MySQL database through NodeMCU wifi. I have no problem with this, but now, in the last few steps before showing it to the company owners, I have problems when I try to reboot NodeMCU after power off.

NodeMCU does not recognize the sketch inside. It is like it was deleted.
I already pulled up gpio0 and gpio2 with 2.2K Ohms resistors and pulled down gpio15 with the same resistor, something recommended by builders.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Thanks

(Sorry for my English, I need to practice more.)

Comment: Not a coding question...

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect GPIO0 to 3V with a pulldown resistor once you have  finished to flash your sketch. This action is setting the NODEMCU devkit to run the sketch, instead of entering in FLASH new sketch mode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Esp8266-01 or esp8266-12E with Nodemcu development board...?

If you are using esp-01 ,after the sketch upload you need to make it Boot from the flash, to load thw sketch

Comment: would you mind expounding on the subject?  I will upvote you if do, but i will NOT downvote you if you don't  ;)